# how do I convert my componentDidMount function to async componentDidMount type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

This is my newsapp and this my News.js file of component folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NeswItem from './NewsItem'

export class News extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      data : null,
loading : false
    }
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    let url = //your news api url
    fetch(url).then((res)=>{
        res.json().then((result)=>{
            console.log(result.articles)
            this.setState({data:result.articles})
        })
    })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      
    <div className="container my-3">
      
      <h2>Top Headlines</h2>
      <div className='row'>
        {this.state.data ?
        this.state.data.map((element)=>
           <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url} >
        <NeswItem title={element.title?.slice(0, 45)} description={element.description?.slice(0, 88)} imgurl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url}/>
        </div>
        )
        : null
        }
        
      </div>

      </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default News
```

I am creating a react app to show latest news and this is my App.js file

```
import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import News from './components/News';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
   
        <News/>
      
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is my NewsItem.js file from component folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class NeswItem extends Component {
  render() {
    let {title, description, imgurl,newsUrl}= this.props;

    return (
     
      <div>
        <div className="card my-3" style={{width: "18rem"}}>
  <img src={!imgurl?"https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-96022092,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-60058,overlay-economictimes/photo.jpg":imgurl} className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
  <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">{title}...</h5>
    <p className="card-text">{description}... </p>
    <a href={newsUrl} target="_blanck" className="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NeswItem
```

I want to convert my componentDidMount function into async componentDidMount one but I was unable to do it. note: I am using my api from newsapi.org

Answer (score 0):

Just use async keyword before componentDidMount

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    let url = //your news api url
    let res = await fetch(url)
    let data = await res.json()
    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea, because React won't do anything with the promise the function returns. At a minimum if you're going to do this, you need to wrap the entire thing in `try`/`catch` to ensure the promise isn't rejected, but fundamentally it's not good practice to implement a function defined by an API with a fundamentally different return value than the API says it has.

Comment: Yeah I just provided the base way because the OP obviously didn't know that a lifecycle function CAN be async. Handling errors was not in the scope I guess, he didn't even handle them in his original code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot behave componentDidMount  asynchronously, and what you did now is ok
if you want to show loading before recieving data you can use your loading state  that you already defined

here is sample :

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading:true})
    let url = //your news api url
    fetch(url).then((res)=>{
        res.json().then((result)=>{
            console.log(result.articles)
            this.setState({data:result.articles,loading:false})
        })
    })
```

and in jsx :

```
  <div>
        {
          this.state.loading ? 'loading...' : null
        }
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert my componentDidMount function into async componentDidMount one

If you did that, it would be misleading. React calls `componentDidMount` and completely ignores any return value it provides. So if you made it `async`, it would return a promise that wouldn't be used by anything.

Instead, either do what you're doing (but handle errors), or write an `async` function to do it and call that function (while handling errors).

The first option:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let url = "your news api url";
    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(({articles}) => {
            console.log(articles);
            this.setState({ data: articles });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        });
}
```

The second:

```
async #getArticles() {
    let url = "your news api url";
    const res = await fetch(url);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
    }
    const { articles } = await res.json();
    console.log(articles);
    this.setState({ data: articles });
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.#getArticles().catch((error) => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    });
}
```

(I've also added a check of `res.ok`, since your code was falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API that  [I describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors like 404 or 500.)